# How to Use OpenCL on Google Pixel 4

Tags: android, opencl, gpgpu, qualcomm

I have Google Pixel 4 and its AOSP source code. But I cannot use OpenCL on Pixel 4.

Existing blogs say that Google doesn't expose OpenCL API to developers.
Is there any way to customize AOSP source code and enable OpenCL API?